# How to do cosmos DB connection with JMeter?

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter, azure-cosmosdb

In `JMeter` how to add connection string of `Cosmos DB` and how to configure all required JDBC driver setting in `JMeter` to connect `Cosmos DB` ?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much you want to invest in terms of money and time the options are in:

1. [Cdata Cosmos DB JDBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/cosmosdb/jdbc/) (as of now it is something like $2k per machine per year). If you go for this option you will have possibility to use JMeter's [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler normally.
2. There is a [Java SDK for CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java), so you can [download client library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.microsoft.azure%20AND%20a:azure-documentdb), add it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and use [DocumentClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.documentclient?view=azure-java-stable) in order to establish connection and perform operations from [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language.

   Check out [NoSQL tutorial: Build a SQL API Java console application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-java-get-started) article for comprehensive instructions, example code, etc.